# Prevent Add-Migration from generating IdentityColumn Annotation?

Tags: .net-core, oracle11g

I am using the Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 2.19.70 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.6 (the last version 2 before 3.0).

Problem:
The CreateTable() call generated by the Add-Migration script adds an annotation call with the IdentityColumn (see below).  This apparently causes a missing ALWAYS keyword error with 11g.

Is there a way I can ask Add-Migration NOT to produce the Annotation call() other than downgrade my libraries?

Thanks!

P.S.  Yes, I have done some Googling, but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this can be addressed by changing the type of the "primary key" property from int to string.

Old:

```
[Key]
[Column(TypeName = "RAW(20)")]
public **int** Id { get; private set;  }
```

New:

```
[Key]
[Column(TypeName = "RAW(20)")]
public **string** Id { get; private set;  }
```